# Eclipse: Can I Bind Commands To The Mouse?

Tags: eclipse, mouse

I'd like to bind the Eclipse command "Toggle Block Selection" ( shift + alt + a ) to be activated when the right mouse button is **held down**, turned off when the right button is released and not be activated at all if the right mouse button is just single clicked ( in that case I'd like the normal context menu to come up ).

Is this possible with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding general gestures to commands is *not* possible in Eclipse 3.x. I believe there are some work underway in Eclipse 4 to support gestures, but I don't know the current state.

There have been a number of plug-ins for Eclipse that will add some limited gestures. Search on the marketplace for them...